How to arrange this Previous, Cancel, Save, and Next button?
I'm building an UI for creating a digital business card. The page has View and Edit mode. In Edit mode, there are 4 buttons:

Previous: go to previous section (e.g. content)
Cancel: exit Edit mode
Save: save the changes
Next: go to next section (e.g. design)


How do you think I should arrange these 4 buttons?

I submitted an answer in the question showed in the banner.
